# Detect if view wants to occuppy more space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view/layout that contains other layouts inside.

The content of those layouts is generated dynamically. Sometimes it happens that the views are truncated/resized (like to many buttons) and a buttons inside a layout are resized.

Is there a way to find out if a layout requested a bigger size than it actually was given?

I tried with hit rect(s), `getMeasuredHeight()` intercepting `onMeasure` but it doesn't seem to be the correct solution.